# Resizing UITableViewCell when entering edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, resize

I have a cell that I have designed in Interface Builder, and when I enter edit mode, it moves the whole cell to the right to make space for the delete icon, but it pushes all items to the right, not shrink them down.  It pushes a UILabel off of the edge of the cell.  Also, this is over the move handles.  How do I shrink these items down, instead of just moving them.

Comment: Hi did you find an answer? Im having same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've never made a custom tableview cell in Interface Builder. So, I don't know how to solve your problem on Interface Builder.
But if you programmatically add all items into the contentView property of UITableViewCell  instead of adding these into UITableViewCell itself, these items would automatically shrink when entering edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution.
On the custom cell object I've created a IBOutlet to the view that holds all subviews in the cell (myContentView).
This way I can run this code to shrink it:

```
OrderReviewCell * cell = (OrderReviewCell * )[reviewTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect frame = cell.myContentView.frame;
frame.size.width = 200;
cell.myContentView.frame = frame;
```

I've figured that the best place to put this is in shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath but my problem is Where to put the code that returns the cell to its normal state?

Hope it helps and DO let me know when you find the right answer!
Gonso